# Use ng-if inside other directive with separate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Currently I've got the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="WaitForViewCtrl">
  <div ng-if="show">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

`WaitForViewCtrl` controller watches `$scope.currentUser` and listens to `$routeChangeSuccess` event and based on the state of these two sets `$scope.show` variable to `true`/`false`. Here's its code https://gist.github.com/szimek/6070c04be07900c87000.

I'd like to change it into a directive, so that it would look like:

```
<div wait-for-view>
  ...
</div>
```

Few questions:

Is there any reason to change it into directive, or is it better to keep it in a controller? If so, how to write such directive?

Is it possible for a directive to have a separate scope, so that it wouldn't pollute other scopes with its own variables like `show`? Or maybe the directive won't have to modify the scope at all?

If I use this directive in many places, would the watchers and listeners be triggered just once for all directives (preferably) or once per directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any reason to change it into directive, or is it better to keep it in a controller? If so, how to write such directive?

In my opinion, directives are useful whenever you want to encapsulate and/or reuse behavior in a declarative way.  If you find yourself doing the same thing over and over again, then I would think that a directive makes sense.  You will need to use [transclusion](http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html), in order to get the inner content hosted inside your directive.  This is a fancy (and often intimidating) name for a very simple concept.

> Is it possible for a directive to have a separate scope, so that it wouldn't pollute other scopes with its own variables like show? Or maybe the directive won't have to modify the scope at all?

Indeed.  Directives can (and often should) have [isolate scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  Giving a directive isolate scope allows it to write to values which it defines as an interface to the user of the directive.

> If I use this directive in many places, would the watchers and listeners be triggered just once for all directives (preferably) or once per directive?

Directives have instance behavior (based on the scope and element), so yes, each one will watch/trigger separately.

Comment: Thanks! Controllers are not singletons in AngularJS, right? Assuming that it's used in many places, there's no performance advantage of using a controller instead of a directive in this case?

Comment: Correct.  Factories are singletons, but controllers and directives are not.